# {a^n b^n c^n | n>=1} - PDA

Tags: automata, context-free, pushdown-automata, context-sensitive

I just started learning context free grammar and Pushdown Automata, I tried implementing this particular language via a PDA, despite being told this language is context sensitive.

How I attempted it is by popping every 2 'a' for 1 'b' and then popping 1 'b' for 2 'c'. I don't understand why is this wrong.

I feel I am be overlooking something really minuscule.

Comment: Your language isn't context-free.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Ik, however what is wrong with my PDA.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/8989/push-down-automata-for-an-bn-cn-n-ge-0?rq=1

Comment: No, the bounds of ‘n’ are different

Comment: There is not much difference between $n \geq 0$ and $n \geq 1$. Try to read past that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you missed something ,

Lets review how your PDA works :

1. we push  a for each a we read
2. we pop 2as for each b we read , then when stack is empty we push b for each b we read
3. we pop b for each 2cs we read

Your PDA will accept strings of form a<sup>2n</sup>b<sup>n+m</sup>c<sup>2m</sup>

for ex , a<sup>4</sup>b<sup>5</sup>c<sup>6</sup> , here n = 2 , m = 3

You push 4 as , then for each 2as you pop b , you pop 2bs , and 3 bs remain which are pushed to stack !!!

Hopefully you can see the problem here , no one told you that you are half way bs when you finished popping as

You continue , for each of the 6 cs you pop a b then you accept

You expect the string in the form a<sup>2n</sup>b<sup>n+m</sup>c<sup>2m</sup> , you compare  a<sup>2n</sup>b<sup>n</sup> then  b<sup>m</sup>c<sup>2m</sup> , of course if n = m you are correct , but there is no way to ensure this

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly the answer I was looking for!